# Solicitar en PHP un archivo de audio vía curl y descargarlo

Tags: php, curl

Tengo 2 servidores linux, servidor1 y servidor2, básicamente necesito que en PHP vía curl el servidor1 solicite un archivo de audio "file.mp3" al servidor2 y que este reciba la petición y como respuesta me envie el archivo de audio "file.mp3", luego en el servidor1 debo ser capaz de recibir como respuesta ese archivo y colocarlo en la carpeta /audios.
Logro con curl conectar los 2 servidores y que el servidor2 me responda pero no he encontrado la forma de enviar y recibir un archivo de audio, gracias.

servidor1:

```
$url = "servidor2/tts/solicitar_audio.php";
$data = array(
        'text' => "file.mp3",
        'idioma' => "es"
);

    $postdata = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
//print_r ($result);
$data = json_decode($result,true);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

servidor2: /tts/solicitar_audio.php

```
$rec=$_SERVER;
$json_params=file_get_contents("php://input");
##Datos recibidos
$decoded_params = json_decode($json_params,true);
$text=$decoded_params['text'];
$idioma=$decoded_params['idioma'];

$file=$text;

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file);
```

Comment: ¿La variable `$send` está vacía?

Comment: Estaba de más ya lo edite, gracias.

Comment: Si quieres el mp3 en `$result`, `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` debería ser `true`.